# How to force stop re-indexing in a MarkLogic database?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

Is it possible to force stop ongoing re-indexing in a MarkLogic database? If yes, how to do it?

Answer (score 4):

You can disable reindexing, but it's worthwhile thinking about what problem you're trying to solve by doing that. Reindexing only happens if you change index settings, and presumably if you change index settings, you'll want the new settings to take effect. If you frequently change index settings and want to control how much resource goes into reindexing, you can also throttle.

To disable reindexing, look here: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/databases#id_28645

Answer (score 2):

Means of disabling reindexing:

1. Using the Admin UI, you can [disable reindexing](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/databases#id_28645):

   - `Databses -> select your content database`
   - in the Configure tab, scroll down to **reindexer enable** and select `false`
   - Scroll to the top or bottom of the page and click the `ok` button
2. Programmatically, use the [`admin:database-set-reindexer-enable()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/admin:database-set-reindexer-enable) function:

   ```
   xquery version "1.0-ml";

   import module namespace admin = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin"
         at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy";

   let $config := admin:get-configuration()
   let $disabled-reindexer-config := admin:database-set-reindexer-enable($config,
       xdmp:database("myDatabase"), fn:false())
   (: returns the new configuration element -- use admin:save-configuration
      to save the changes to the configuration or pass the configuration
      to other Admin API functions to make other changes.  :)
   return
     admin:save-configuration( $disabled-reindexer-config )
   ```

Rather than disabling reindexing, you can also adjust the throttle level through the Admin UI or by using [`admin:database-set-reindexer-throttle()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/admin:database-set-reindexer-throttle), in order to minimize the performance impact.

https://developer.marklogic.com/blog/mitigating-the-impact-of-re-indexing